# Loop through SQL files in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, tfs

I am trying to loop through each sql file in a folder and run the script on a database.  This is what i currently have.

```
#Provide SQLServerName
$SQLServer ="xxx\xxx"
#Provide Database Name
$DatabaseName ="xxx"
#Database User
$User ="xx"
#Database Password
$Password ="xxx"
#Scripts Folder Path
$FolderPath ="\\xxxs\xxx\xxx\xxx\"

#Loop through the .sql files and run them
foreach ($filename in get-childitem -path $FolderPath -filter "*.sql")
{
    invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -Username $User -Password $Password -InputFile $filename.fullname
    #Print file name which is executed
    $filename
}
```

When this runs i get the following error

```
At C:\Agent\_work\8\s\Deploy\dbRun.ps1:15 char:21
+ invoke-sqlcmd â?"ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName
-Username ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Agent\_work\8\s\Deploy\dbRun.ps1:14 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I cannot figure out what I'm missing causing this error.  I see the close }

Comment: In your $User variable declaration/assignment, does your real file actually contain a closing quote? I know your example shows "xx" but the error message indicates it's not actually closed.

Comment: yea, all quotes are there.

Comment: It looks like the dash before `ServerInstance` is not a dash. `invoke-sqlcmd â?"ServerInstance`

Comment: Good eye.  I've edited what i get after i fix

Comment: @Adam your suggestoin was the issue. and i did have the wrong password.

Comment: Sometimes even a blind squirrel finds a nut. :-)

Comment: @TheDizzle, Do you resolve this issue now? If it has been resolved, you could share your solution as the answer and mark it. So it could help other community members.